# Javascript generators with the 'yield' keyword

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, canvas, yield-keyword

I'm experimenting with HTML5's new canvas tag, in which I render and animate some simple shapes. My canvas's script has the following function:

```
function initializeSquarePositions(rows, columns) {
    for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += canvas.width / columns)
        for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += canvas.height / rows)
            yield {x: x, y: y};
}
```

For some reason, this code executes wonderfully in Firefox, but it does not work at all in Chrome. Both browsers are the latest version, and I have my script tag marked as version=1.8 (version=1.7 didn't work either).

Is the 'yield' keyword not working in Chrome or something? I sure hope it does; generators make for cleaner code!

I couldn't find any concrete yes or no answers to that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators and Generators are (for now) Mozilla-extensions, this means that you will be able to use them only on Mozilla Implementations (JavaScript (TM)).

I said "for now" because those features will be probably introduced in the next version of the ECMAScript Standard, [ECMAScript Harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals%3aiterators_and_generators).

Comment: This answer is now out of date as `yield` was just added to Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the 'yield' keyword not working in Chrome or something?

That's it. Sorry. `yield` and `let` aren't in Chrome (or Opera, or Safari, or IE) yet.

Comment: Really? Chrome is really lagging behind there... Generators and iterators have been supported by Mozilla since Firefox 2 (August 2008, I believe)!

Comment: This answer is now out of date as `yield` was just added to Google Chrome.

Comment: Where? In Canary? It's certainly not in Stable, and its not in Dev.